# What is the necessasity of # in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

If my html is as like below

```
<div id="TestHash"> </div>
```

I can access it as `$("#TestHash")` , `$(TestHash)`. Both will result the same.
what is the usage of element without # ??

Comment: both wont result same. check properly. second selector will throw error as `TestHash` is used as variable.

Comment: There should be error with `$(TestHash)`.

Comment: $(TestHash) should crash, since there is no var TestHash defined. So, it's equal to $(undefined);

Comment: They are not same. Only possibility of them giving the same result is that you have `var TestHash =  $("#TestHash")` or `var TestHash =  document.getElementById("TestHash")` above the second.

Comment: I tested through browser console  and then only raised a question.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Id's are always added as property to the global object. It's pretty much legacy but it works.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl exactly! - people need to not rush to jump on a question when they aren't so sure. It's actually a very valid question, and I can see why suresh would be thrown

Comment: Quite a valid question actually. Just noticed this weird behavior as well! +1 for bringing it up.

Comment: @suresh, deleted my answer cause I didn't know it functioned that way. I could not replicate the behavior in my Chrome console, infact it threw up an error. Upvoting the question.The answer by Chris makes perfect sense.

Comment: @SatejS tried with FF Firebug console. Works perfectly! No error. selecter exactly behaves like '#selecter'

Comment: Remember in Chrome the `$` is also rolled in - so it might not actually be using jQuery

Comment: @guest420420, that's interesting  cause I couldn't replicate it in my FF version. The best part is, even my IE version threw an error.

Comment: @SatejS Windows, FF version 45.0.2. Firebug version 2.0.16  over here.

Comment: @SatejS did you try it with a id without any special characters? Id's with special characters like `question-header` won't work as the dash isn't valid as identifier in JS.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl, yep!Tried something along the lines of `$(content)`

Answer (score 6):

In fact, there is a legacy artefact in Javascript - elements with an ID automatically populate global namespace.

This is why you can access it directly the way you are (`$(TestHash)`). However, it's a misunderstood piece left over from legacy browsers, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Where possible, always use the `$("#myId")` version.

Comment: I always use with # only . I saw some code with out selectors . I was surprised with out any exception. It is working fine. I need to know how it works. That is the theme i posted here.

Comment: Yep fair call - try to avoid it. I don't think it will be dropped as a feature in browsers anytime soon - but it will cause issues when you start to modularise your js and what not.

Comment: +1 was about to write an answer myself earlier and link to some resource with more info but it's surprisingly hard to find anything about it... Only thing I know of is that it's chapter 14.7 in 'Javascript: The Definitive Guide (6th edition)'

Comment: Ditto - I can't find any further info - I just remembered it from yonks ago